# Want to add 3 Strings to an Array in Javascript with a button

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming. Right now I'm trying to add a few strings that are given in a form in HTML to an array thats stored inside a Jscript. The relevant code:

```
<input type="text" id="fName" placeholder="Vorname" /> 
<input type="text" id="fNachname" placeholder="Nachname" /> 
<input type="email" id="fEmail"  placeholder="E-Mail" /> 
<button id="formSubmit" > Absenden </button>
```

And here the jscript:

```
document.getElementById("formSubmit").addEventListener("click", Person);



function Person(vorname, name, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.vorname = vorname;
    this.email = email;
}

var Personen = [
    new Person(document.getElementById("fName"), document.getElementById("fNachname"), document.getElementById("fEmail")  )

]
document.getElementById("formSubmit").addEventListener("click", console.log(Personen));
```

But right now, it does not show in the console when I give the array a person. It simply gives me the code that is stored inside the Personen variable. How can I resolve this?

Comment: this code is totally incorrect...

Comment: you want put the inputed value in an array?

Comment: @AnamulHasan Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Proxytype Yes, I know, thats why I'm asking for help. Sorry for bad coding, as I said I'm really new. Started with jscript today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Person(vorname, name, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.vorname = vorname;
    this.email = email;
}

var Personen = [];
var addPerson = function() {
    Personen.push(new Person(document.getElementById("fName").value, document.getElementById("fNachname").value, document.getElementById("fEmail").value  ));
    console.log( Personen);
}

document.getElementById("formSubmit").addEventListener("click", addPerson);
```

```html
    <body class='home'>
        <input type="text" id="fName" placeholder="Vorname" />
        <input type="text" id="fNachname" placeholder="Nachname" />
        <input type="email" id="fEmail"  placeholder="E-Mail" />
        <button id="formSubmit" > Absenden </button>
    </body>
```

```
function Person(vorname, name, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.vorname = vorname;
    this.email = email;
}

var Personen = [];
var addPerson = function() {
    Personen.push(new Person(document.getElementById("fName").value, document.getElementById("fNachname").value, document.getElementById("fEmail").value  ));
    console.log( Personen);
}

document.getElementById("formSubmit").addEventListener("click", addPerson);
```

this should add a person when you submit

Comment: Sadly it doesn't :( 
It doesn't log anything back in the console

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in as an object and not as function

```
var Personen = new Array();
Personen.push({name : document.getElementById("fName"),vorname :document.getElementById("fNachname"),email : document.getElementById("fEmail")  })
```